# Strange pandas nameless column

Tags: python, pandas

My csv file looks like this.

```
,timestamp,side,size,price,tickDirection,grossValue,homeNotional,foreignNotional
0,1569974396.557895,1,11668,8319.5,1,140248813.0,11668,1.40248813
1,1569974394.78865,0,5000,8319.0,0,60103377.0,5000,0.60103377
2,1569974392.355395,0,564,8319.0,0,6779660.999999999,564,0.06779661
3,1569974383.797042,0,100,8319.0,0,1202067.0,100,0.01202067
4,1569974382.944569,0,3,8319.0,0,36062.0,3,0.00036062
5,1569974382.944569,0,7412,8319.0,-1,89097247.0,7412,0.89097247
```

There's a nameless index column. I want to remove this column.
When I read this in pandas, it just interprets it as an index and moves on.
The problem is, when you now use `df[::-1]`, it flips the indexes as well. So `df[::-1]['timestamp][0]` is the same as `df['timestamp'][0]` if the file was read with indexes, but not if it was read without.

How do I make it actually ignore the index column so that `df[::-1]` doesn't flip my indexes?

I tried `usecols` in `read_csv`, but it doesn't matter, it reads the indexes as well as the columns specified. I tried `del df['']`, but it doesn't work because it doesn't interpret the index column as column `''`, even though that's what it is.

Comment: `pandas.read_csv(<filename>, index=[0])` and then `pandas.to_csv(<filename>, index=False`), and finally after that `pandas.read_csv(<filename>, index=None)`

Comment: There is no index parameter in the read_csv function. Maybe this changed.

Comment: Works with index_col=[0], thanks. Keeping it unanswered tho in case there's a solution that doesn't require rewriting the file.

Comment: oh yeah, `index_col` for read_csv -- my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `index_col=0`

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0)
print(df)

# Output
      timestamp  side   size   price  tickDirection   grossValue  homeNotional  foreignNotional
0  1.569974e+09     1  11668  8319.5              1  140248813.0         11668         1.402488
1  1.569974e+09     0   5000  8319.0              0   60103377.0          5000         0.601034
2  1.569974e+09     0    564  8319.0              0    6779661.0           564         0.067797
3  1.569974e+09     0    100  8319.0              0    1202067.0           100         0.012021
4  1.569974e+09     0      3  8319.0              0      36062.0             3         0.000361
5  1.569974e+09     0   7412  8319.0             -1   89097247.0          7412         0.890972
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you issue, you can just set timestamp as your index:

```
df.set_index('timestamp', drop = True)
```

Comment: That works, thanks. My timestamps aren't unique so really I want no index, but it solves the problem.